# Shared cache between two WebViews

Tags: android, caching, webview, browser-cache

Is it possible to enable caching between multiple webviews? Here is the scenario:

1. Activity A with WebView 1 is created to show xyz.com
2. Later Activity B with WebView 2 is created to show xyz.com again

I tried `webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);` but the page (I use a large wikipedia page for testing) is still reloaded from the web instead of using the cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), all WebViews in an application share their cache.

However, it looks like Wikipedia always sets the response headers in such a way as to mark the response un-cacheable:

```
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

So, I don't think that you're doing anything wrong, nor do I think that there is anything that you can to fix the situation with Wikipedia. Try a different web site, that uses a more 'normal' caching policy, and I'm sure that you will see the WebView's cache working as you expect.

Comment: And I thought "Which page should I pick for testing.. oh Wikipedia has only static content, perfect"

Comment: "According to the documentation, all WebViews in an application share their cache." There's nothing in the documentation you linked to which states this. It says "your application has its own cache, cookie store" but to clarify that it doesn't share state with the browser. Doesn't mean necessarily that all the webviews in the application share the same cache.

Comment: If you read the documentation for the clearCache method, it says, "Clears the resource cache. Note that the cache is per-application, so this will clear the cache for all WebViews used".

Comment: Upvoted for clarifying its per application basis and all webview are affected